# App crashes while playing video in dailog box

Tags: android

I want my app to play video in a `DialogBox` on a button click.

When the button is pressed a new dailog box appears saying can't play this video

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
 {
Context context;
String VideoURL = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
@Override
public void playvideo(View v){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.videodialog);
    dialog.show();
    MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
        MainActivity.this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    final VideoView videoview = (VideoView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.videodialogVideoView);
    mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
    videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
    videoview.start();

}
  }
```

Comment: Is your onClick action in your layout.xml defined? If it is, please check the naming.

Comment: @Christopher Yeah it is defined and it is same

Comment: Besides the crash, I am 1000% sure this code will not do what you think it does. I suggest you search how to display YouTube videos  in-app.

Comment: @EdGeorge Its not only YouTube videos. Just set the url for testing

Comment: If your app  supports only yoututbe video then videoview will not work for it.You need to use `Youtube player api` for it. https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: Well it's a poor URL to use, as it will not work. May I suggest reading the [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) and [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)

Comment: @Beena No I want other videos to play. Just set the url for testing

Comment: @EdGeorge What if I used other video url

Comment: Your `context`varible null. You should use `MainActivity.this`

Comment: @user5524159, I have one doubt that you have extended Activity so how you Override the method, even you have not implemented interface.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Tried it . the dailog box opens but another dailog box pops up saying can't play this video. Even tried changing the url

Comment: Dude check video URL. It may be not proper URL or not supported to play.

Comment: @PiyushGupta I tried changing various URLs ,still the same

Comment: @Beena I have added the edited code  in the question. Now it's saying can't play this video

Comment: @EdGeorge  I have added the edited code in the question. Now it's saying can't play this video

Comment: @PiyushGupta  I have added the edited code in the question. Now it's saying can't play this video

Comment: Again, please read the Android docs - your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research.

Comment: @user5524159 Its perfectly playing a video at my side. Did you add internet permission and network access permission?

Comment: Then it should be permission issue

Comment: @Beena Hi. From ahmedabad?

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta : nope.